# How does twitter implement TsarJob in Scala?

Tags: scala

Sorry for the ambiguous title but i'm referring to a blog post by Twitter on their internal system [TSAR](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/tsar-a-timeseries-aggregator) which they use to do time series aggregation on streams of Thrift objects.

I'm new to Scala so I don't understand how their scala code for the ImpressionJob refers to individual fields in the ImpressionAttributes Thrift object.

The example they give has Thrift definition:

```
enum Client
{
  iPhone = 0,
  Android = 1,
  ...
}

struct ImpressionAttributes
{
   1: optional Client client,
   2: optional i64 user_id,
   3: optional i64 tweet_id
}
```

And TSAR job (scala code)

```
object ImpressionJob extends TsarJob[ImpressionAttributes] {
  aggregate {
    onKeys(
      (TweetId),
      (TweetId, ClientApplicationId)
    ) produce (
      Count,
      Unique(UserId)
    ) sinkTo (Manhattan, MySQL)
  } fromProducer {
    ClientEventSource(“client_events”)
      .filter { event => isImpressionEvent(event) }
      .map { event =>
        val impr = ImpressionAttributes(
          event.client, event.userId, event.tweetId
        )
        (event.timestamp, impr)
      }
   }
}
```

Where are TweetId, ClientApplicationId and UserId defined. I understand that they refer to fields in the class of the job but not sure how these aliases are defined. The blog post implies that they aren't defined elsewhere.

Comment: Are you looking for [Scrooge](https://github.com/twitter/scrooge) (Twitter's Scala code generator for Thrift)?

Comment: Maybe ... After reading through the Scrooge docs I don't see anywhere about generating what looks like classes for each field in a thrift structure. I'm definitely missing something